# How can i type linux commands after using ruby script/server to set up a local server?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I am new to programming and ruby on rails. This question may be a little dumb.

After I set up a server(basically an empty one) in Ubuntu terminal using the "ruby script/server" command. My "usersname:~$" label is gone and the only way I know how to type in terminal again is to shutdown the server or Ctril + z. How do i keep the server running while I try to edit the contents of my server(such as writing controller)?

Answer (score 2):

Use ruby script/server &. Adding & will run the server in bacground

Comment: Note that this is equivalent to using Ctrl+Z, as you are doing.

Answer (score 2):

Open another terminal ,

cd app_directory

and run any command you want. As a result your commands won't be affected due to page load